# Using NOT IN and count with query

Tags: sql, mysql

Having problems with A count of the number of customers who have not hired cars

```
create table customer
(customer_id  char(4) primary key not null,
customer_sname varchar (30) not null,
customer_fname varchar (30) not null,
customer_title varchar (6) not null,
customer_address1 varchar (35) not null,
customer_address2 varchar (35) null,
customer_postcode varchar (25) null,
customer_phone varchar (30) null,
customer_email varchar (40) null,
customer_di varchar (40) not null)
ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table car_booking
(booking_id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT primary key not null,
car_id char (4) not null,
customer_id char (4)  not null,
hire_sdate date not null,
hire_edate date not null)
engine=innodb;
```

This doesn't seem to work

```
SELECT customer_id count(*) 
FROM customer
WHERE customer_id not IN
(SELECT booking_id FROM car_booking
```

help me :-(

Comment: Formatting, please.  Use the toolbar at the top of the edit box.  Select each block of code and press the icon with 1's and 0's.

Comment: +1 for posting your table structure. This makes things much easier. You would have gotten +2 if you also explained *why* you think your query doesn't work and what error message you get. Except StackOverflow doesn't allow me to vote +2.

Comment: @skygirl I don't want to be rude, but you haven't accepted an answer for any of your questions, despite your indication in a comment that an answer worked.

Answer (score 2):

Two errors:

- Your select statement shouldn't include both the customer number and the count.
- Your subselect was selecting the booking id instead of the customer id.

Try this:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM customer
WHERE customer_id NOT IN
(SELECT customer_id FROM car_booking)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should also work.  IMO it's better than a subquery.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM customer
LEFT JOIN car_booking
ON customer.customer_id = car_booking.customer_id
WHERE car_booking.customer_id IS NULL
```

Edit: The explanation.

The LEFT JOIN will bring in all records from the table customer, even those that don't have a record in car_booking.  Meanwhile, in the joined result set, car_booking.customer_id will be NULL for all entries in customer that don't have an entry in car_booking.  The WHERE clause specifies just these rows, which COUNT(*) counts.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma and `GROUP BY` clause; it should be:

```
SELECT customer_id, count(*) 
FROM customer
WHERE customer_id not IN
(SELECT booking_id FROM car_booking)
GROUP BY customer_id
```